# Facebook sharing feature on seam

Tags: java, xhtml, facebook, jsf, seam

Good morning all.

I'm developing a web application, using Seam.

I have the following problem:

I have my site with Locale set to "en".
I'm trying to share a specific page: ../pt/news.xhtml?id=8
The first portion of this url (/pt/) "tells" the webserver that the article displayed on news.xhtml page with id=8 must be in portuguese. To do that, on my pages.xml, i'm capturing this view and applying the Locale ("pt" in this case).

if i access the link ../pt/news.xhtml?id=8 directly from a browser, the page is showned in portuguese, but if share this page on facebook, the content displayed on facebook popup it's in english.

Does anyone knows what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check whether on the request from facebook you are actually setting the locale (put a breakpoint (if using remote debugging), or put detailed debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would run the URL thru the linter tool at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and ensure that it is reading your OG tags correctly.  Be sure to specify the og:locale correctly doe the language you want it to pick it up as.